# Running python script in through a bat file in a ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, python, batch-file

I'm trying to run a python script. It runs a trained model from keras. 
I worked with a C# Web API. I've cracked my head trying to make the python script run. I've made it through a .bat file. It works perfectly on a windows form project. And the bat itself works fine as well.
The issue comes when the Web API wants to run the .bat file, for some reason 
it when I run the script through IIS Express it won't recognize the data.csv file that the model is supposed to read.

Let me show you some code 
Run the bat file

```
           System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"pathtobatfile\runner.bat");
```

bat file

```
pathtoenviroment\python.exe pathtoscript\AI.py %*
PAUSE
```

Allright, so when I run it outside IIS Express it works fine but when I run it on the Web API ...

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "D:\AIASSETS\AI.py", line 13, in 
>       q = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
>     File "C:\Users\Marco\Anaconda3\envs\entornotensor\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 678, in parser_f
>       return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>     File "C:\Users\Marco\Anaconda3\envs\entornotensor\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 440, in _read
>       parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
>     File "C:\Users\Marco\Anaconda3\envs\entornotensor\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 787, in **init**
>       self._make_engine(self.engine)
>     File "C:\Users\Marco\Anaconda3\envs\entornotensor\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1014, in _make_engine
>       self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
>     File "C:\Users\Marco\Anaconda3\envs\entornotensor\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1708, in **init**
>       self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
>     File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 384, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.**cinit**
>     File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 695, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
>   FileNotFoundError: File b'data.csv' does not exist

but it does actually exist, this just happens when I run it from the Web API.

some extra information: the bat file takes a long time to run the python script. but the script itself runs instantaneously. 
the data.csv file is generated through code and it generates correctly. Could it be that the file takes too long to write itself and the batch file runs before the data.csv is written? I made some tests in another project but the data.csv was written instantaneously.

Thanks in advance
Edit:
I've just checked debugging and even with a Thread sleep that the data.csv is not taking too long to build. IIS console just won't let the python script read the data.csv file

Comment: Isn't it easier to add the IronPython NuGet package to your project and run your script directly?

Comment: I tried IronPython, but it's super complicated to install libraries to IronPython, and as far as I know you can't install other libraries that are numpy and scipy. and I need keras and pandas.  So for now IronPython is not the way to go for me...

Comment: I had a little experience, when there was no other way to interact with external application except running the other process but I didn't save any files on disk, I just passed all the information through the command-line arguments, then read all of the information from stdout. Maybe it will worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the account the website uses in IIS? As it could be a permission issue if its using the networkservice account.

Comment: could you elaborate on how to change the account please? I can't find good information so far

Comment: open IIS, select the site in question, go to basic settings then click 'connect as'

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the issue was. 
as I'm running the script outside the environment, and I'm calling the interpreter from a Process class, there's no way for the script to know what is the working folder. It assumes it to be where the interpreter is. the solution is very straight forward, just add the path in the script.
something like this:

```
q = pd.read_csv('D:\\AIASSETS\\data.csv')
```

and wherever you use a file add "D:\AIASSETS\" or better said whatever your working folder is. 
even in your model or if you're writing a file. 
I'm not to worded on python, but I believe there's a way to set the working folder by code as well, that might work too.